# Trying to install Nbox on CentOS 7 throws dependency error for mod_auth_xradius. Installing the mod from source etc. does not work

Tags: linux, centos7, ntop

I was trying to set up Ntop for testing purposes on a Virtualbox running CentOS 7.

When trying to run `yum install nbox` I get the following error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nbox-2.3.0-368.noarch (ntop-noarch)
            Requires: mod_auth_xradius
```

So far I have looked alot of different options but even installing the mod from source has yielded no success.

Has anyone else run into this issue before?

Best regards

Comment: What options have you tried?  (also, [see this](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html))

Comment: Unless you actually create a RPM package installing something from source will never solve a yum/rpm dependancy, even though the dependancy in the actual software might indeed be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use stable repository:

http://packages.ntop.org/apt-stable/

Please install now again and it will work.

The dev repository will be fix in few days.

Comment: How will using an apt repo help for a yum problem?